# Dockerize MERN stack using traefik

Tags: docker, traefik

I did follow this tutorial : https://rafrasenberg.com/posts/docker-container-management-with-traefik-v2-and-portainer/ to build a treafik reverse proxy on my server

And I tested it with a very simple application that render a "hello world" in a index.html:

```json
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: nginx
    environment:
      PORT: ${PORT}
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/share/nginx/html/
    networks:
      - proxy
      - default
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app-secure.rule=Host(`my-test.localhost`)"
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

it works!

Now I want to go on the next step and use it to build a MERN stack project and I'm a bit lost.

usually I dockerize a mern stack by:

- create a dockerfile in /server
- create a dockerfile in /client
- create a docker-compose on the root directory

```json
version: "3.7"

services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: myapp-server
    container_name: myapp-node-server
    command: /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon server.js
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 5000
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    env_file: ./server/.env
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - app-network
      - proxy
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017
    networks:
      - app-network
      - proxy
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: myapp-client
    container_name: myapp-react-client
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./client/:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - server
    ports:
      - 3001
    networks:
      - app-network
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2-secure.rule=Host(`test.localhost`)"

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
  proxy:
    external: true
volumes:
  data-volume:
  node_modules:
  web-root:
    driver: local
```

But seems that my proxy not working because the console doesn't return any error and it works on localhost:3000 but on test.localhost I have a "Gateway Timeout" error

Comment: You say you're using Traefik, but you run an Nginx image. That confuses me.

Comment: Why ? The nginx image is just an exemple of how I use the stack to render a "hello world" in a index.html.

Comment: Where is your Traefik image then? There's no mention of one in any of the files you've posted.

Comment: I use this stack https://github.com/rafrasenberg/docker-traefik-portainer then in the apps/ folder I can create differents  projects